# Best approach for passing strongly named parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-core

How can you create an Interface method where the type of input and output is unknown, but the received parameters should be strongly named?

I am working on an application which anonymizes data. I created an Interface class, called IAnonymizer, which is implemented by multiple different anonymizers. Each anonymizer anonymizes different types of data, so the input and output is different for each anonymizer.
The Interface contains an Anonymize() method and because the type of input, output and amount of parameters is unknown, I decided a Dictionary object would be the best solution. The dictionary allows me to add a name to each value, this way I know what a certain value represents.

Currently my Anonymize method looks like this:

```
Optional<Dictionary<string, object>> Anonymize(Dictionary<string, object> values);
```

An example of the input for an AddressAnonymizer, could be something like this:

```
"city", "Amsterdam"
"street", "Stationsplein"
"housenumber", 1
"zipcode", "1012 AB"
```

The code I have so far works fine, but sometimes it seems a bit excessive when there is only a single value as input and output (for example when anonymizing an IBAN value). What other options are there to create an Interface method with unknown input and output, but having them strongly named as well?

Comment: Are you describing generics?

Comment: *"The code I have so far works fine"*, then you probably want [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), make sure to check their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), currently your question is off-topic for them and too broad for SO.

Comment: "but sometimes it seems a bit excessive when there is only a single value as input and output". Are you aware of collection initialisers? They make initialising dictionaries look pretty.

Comment: Create dedicated type(class) for every input, with such approach you will be able to configure anonymizers to accept one or multiple input types ---- Generics

Comment: Where does that `Dictionary<string, object> values` come from? Did you use reflection? If you want `Anonymize` to be strongly typed, convert it into a generic method and use reflection on the type. You can use Marc Gravel's [FastMember](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) library to make access through reflection faster

Comment: At the bank we look at items that need to be covered by law, so look for all properties that can identify the client and replace them with Random valued or mask by them day you do iban XX-XXX-XXX-12345, or address types like country and city. also there are levels of masking production data that may be less problematic when inhouse or external. I guess implementing that granularityand keyword would help speed thinks up

Comment: The answer greatly depends on the purpose of the abstraction you're trying to create. Do you have a list of abstract anonymizers that you invoke in a loop? Also very important - where do the inputs and the parameters of each anonymizer come from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem. You have some set objects with data (DTOs). you want to apply anonimization of this objects. Each Attribute/property of each object may require to use different type of anonymizer. You would like to create a service that will take as input an instance of object, check if they contain data that need to be anonymized, anonymize it and then put anonymized output. Am i right?

If i understood you correctly, you could potentially use Attributes to define in property what anonymizer should be applied to. if property does not need to be anonymized, you just simply don't apply attribute. you can define your custom attribute as follows:

```
public class AnonymizerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type Type { get; }

    public AnonymizerAttribute(Type anonymizerType)
    {
        Type = anonymizerType;
    }
}
```

then you implement each anonymizer and pack them with shared interface (for example as those):

```
public interface IAnonymizer
{
    object Anonymize(object input);
}
public class NameAnonymizer: IAnonymizer
{
    public object Anonymize(object input)
    {
        return "AnonymizedName";
    }
}
public class SomeAnonymizer: IAnonymizer
{
    public object Anonymize(object input)
    {
        return "AnonymizedSomething";
    }
}
```

and now you create generic method that anonymizes any input that has applied valid attributes and anonymizers implement shared interface:

```
public T Anonymize<T>(T input)
    {
        var inputType = input.GetType();

        //to anonymize attributes, duplicate this loop but use inputType.GetAttributes()
        foreach (var prop in inputType.GetProperties())
        {
            var anonymizerAttribute =  (AnonymizerAttribute) prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AnonymizerAttribute));

            if (anonymizerAttribute != null)
            {
                var anonymizerObj = Activator.CreateInstance(anonymizerAttribute.Type);
                if (anonymizerObj is IAnonymizer anonymizer)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(input, anonymizer.Anonymize(prop.GetValue(input)));
                }
            }
        }

        return input;
    }
```

the last thing is to apply attributes to objects taht you want to anonymize (like so)

```
public class DataClass
{
    [Anonymizer(typeof(SomeAnonymizer))] 
    public string Iban { get; set; }

    [Anonymizer(typeof(NameAnonymizer))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; } //No anonymization done here
}
```

keep in mind that in my example code i anonymize only properties, so `public string Iban { get; set; }` will be anonymized, but attribute defined as `public string Iban;` won't be anonymized. if you want to anonymize both propertirs and attributes, all you need to do is to copy foreach loop from `public T Anonymize<T>(T input)` but change element it iterates from `inputType.GetProperties()` to `inputType.GetAttributes()`